# Retrive Journeys by OrderBy Does not work

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I am trying to retrieve Journeys by specifying the **orderBy** in the URL parameters in a REST request ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm)). Here is the request URL parameters:

> Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions?$page=1&$pageSize=50&orderBy=Name+ASC&mostRecentVersionOnly=False'

This obviously does not work if there are more than one pages (each page is set to have 50 records).
Is there something I need to specify to make this work? Or what am I doing wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm), there's a typo in the docs on this page. The parameter of the query string to order results is "$orderBy" and not "orderBy".

This usage correctly orders results:

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions?$page=1&$pageSize=50&extras=stats&$orderBy=name%20ASC